# How to make checkbox into datagridview checked based of sql database

Tags: checkbox, datagridview

I am new at vb.net programming ,So my question is any simple way to make each checkbox at the rows into my datagridview checked based of the database values and compare between my datagridview values and my database values and return whats the same between both as checked to the datagridview checkbox .
Thanks.

**Here is my code:**

```
        Try

            For Each Chckstutus As DataGridViewRow In theDataGridView.Rows
                Dim ASD As String = Chckstutus.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
                Dim myConnectionString As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Checktools\Checktools\CheckDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
                myConnectionString.Open()
                Dim query As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerID FROM dbo.TempPrint where CustomerID = " & ASD & "", myConnectionString)
                Dim Results As String = query.ExecuteScalar().ToString()

                If ASD = Results Then
                    Chckstutus.Cells.Item("chkbox").Value = True
                    Chckstutus.Cells.Item("chkbox").ReadOnly = True
                Else
                    Chckstutus.Cells.Item("chkbox").Value = False
                    Chckstutus.Cells.Item("chkbox").ReadOnly = False
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: What problem are you facing with code you added?

Comment: I think it's a small problem but it still a problem,The code is working fine but it tell me "object reference not set to an instance of an object" I don't know why ,Can you help me ,Thanks.

Comment: Check whether you have a column with name "chkbox"

Comment: Many Thanks for your help Junaith and sorry about the late i was out of the country.